# Laravel Passport - How do you disallow users from generating clients?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Passport provides a convenient way of registering routes for users to create their own clients by calling Passport::routes(); in the AuthServiceProvider.

I do not wish to allow my users to create clients, as I only want to manually create clients using `php artisan passport:client` command, as I only need passport for machine-to-machine authentication for internal services.

How do I customize routes for Passport to only expose the necessary routes for passing a client id and secret to gain an access_token? I understand that I can dig into the framework and expose my own routes to a series of \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PassportController@action, I just didn't know if that was the only way or the preferred way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a closure to `Passport::routes()` in your AuthServiceProvider.
See [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/Passport.php#L153)

In the closure you can define which routes should be registered.

Something like this:

```
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
    $router->forAuthorization();
    $router->forAccessTokens();
    // etc.
);
```

[Here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/RouteRegistrar.php) are the available methods:

```
forAuthorization();
forAccessTokens();
forTransientTokens();
forClients();
forPersonalAccessTokens();
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with the newest version of Passport, now it's `Passport::ignoreRoutes()` and then you have to define them yourself.